# Search for email address with the pattern [at]/(at) in python

Tags: python, regex

I am developing a web scraper code. The basic thing which I am retrieving is email address from the HTML source. I am using the following code

```
 r = re.compile(r"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b", re.IGNORECASE)
 emailAddresses =  r.findall(html)
```

In few websites the email address is in the format abcd[at]gmail.com/abcd(at)gmail.com. I need a generic regex code which will retrieve email address in either of the three formats abcd[at]gmail.com/abcd(at)gmail.com/abcd@gmail.com. I tried the following code, but didn't get expected result. Can any one help me.

```
 r = re.compile(r"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[@|(at)|[at]][A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b", re.IGNORECASE)
     emailAddresses =  r.findall(html)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Solution:** Replace `@` by `(@|\(at\)|\[at\])` as such:

```
r = re.compile(r"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(@|\(at\)|\[at\])[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b", re.IGNORECASE)
emailAddresses =  r.findall(html)
```

**Explanation:** In your attempt, you did `[one|two|three]`, you cannot do that. `[…]` is used for single characters or for sets (`[a-z]` is the same as `[abcd…xyz]`). You must use `(one|two|three)` instead. [1]

Also, you attempt to match `()` and `[]` which are all special characters regarding to REGEX, so they have special functionality. If you want to actually match them (and not using their special functionality), you must remember to escape them before by putting a `\` in front of them. Same goes for `.?+*` etc.

**Suggestion:** You can also try to match `[dot]` and `(dot)` that very same way if you wish so.

Just remember that there are a ton of way to obfuscate email addresses out there, including some you might not be aware of.

And that, also, validating email addresses (and so trying to catch them with REGEX) can be very tricky:

The actual official REGEX is `` (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\]) ``.

(**EDIT: Source:** http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html Looks like it could be even worse than the above REGEX!!)

[1] Beware that using `(…)` will capture its content, if you wish this content not being captured you have to use `(?:…)` instead.

Comment: plus one for the killer regex, can you add a source?

Answer (score 0):

```
 r = re.compile(r"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(?:@|[(\[]at[\])])[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b", re.IGNORECASE)

                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
 emailAddresses =  r.findall(html)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nD5jY4/5#python

Comment: Other way to write what I did. Nice that you added a live demo! Btw, AFAIK, you do not need to escape the first `[`, only the `]` has its effect in `[…]` (And `-`, unless put at the very end)